# How to return a string from an ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call, passing as parameter an integer 'mySensor'. The php file of the call contains the following code:

```
<?php

 $con = mysql_connect(...) or die('connection not made');
 $db = mysql_select_db('...', $con) or die('db not selected');

 $mySensor = mysql_escape_string($_POST["mySensor"]);
 $query = "SELECT Unit FROM sensors WHERE SensorID = ".$mySensor;
 $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');

 echo $result;

?>
```

So, from the table `sensors` I want to get the `Unit` (which is a string) of the element with `SensorID=mySensor` (there is only one such element). Echoing the `$result` doesn't work. How do I return that unit (which is, again, a string) back to my js script?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any libraries (e.g., jQuery, Mootools), or just vanilla javascript?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** (`mysql_escape_string` has never been sufficient) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @jboneca, he's asking about how to do server-side stuff.

Comment: @JonathanM Mhmm, and then he mentions how to return and presumably use this within the context of JavaScript. Echoing within a php script is not enough to "return that unit" through ajax.

Comment: @jboneca, ok. I don't think he's asking about his client side stuff. If you think so, ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to fetch the results of that query ie:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $array['Unit'];
```

Another thing is that `mysql_escape_string()`, where unless you are already declaring a function with that name, then it is not the actual `mysql_real_escape_string` library function

```
 $mySensor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mySensor"]);
```

**Important**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a modern replacement.  You are also **vulnerable to SQL injection attacks** (`mysql_escape_string` has never been sufficient) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from

Comment: Shouldn't that be `echo $array['Unit'];`?